# Visual Studio 2012 documentation download

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Around 2006 Microsoft used to give away ISO images of the MSDN libraries. Unfortunately they don't do this anymore. Now if you want to have local help, you have to download it from the Visual Studio environment. The problem is that I just installed Visual Studio 2012 on a home PC with no internet access.

Anyone knows how to download a copy of the documentation that I can manually install on my PC?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the ISO for the Visual Studio 2012 documentation here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34794

It's 2.7GB large.

UPDATE:
Microsoft has added the ISO for Visual Studio 2013 documentation to the same link as above.

That ISO is 4GB large.

Comment: thanks! And just to clarify, this is available for everyone, not just MSDN subscribers.

Comment: A useful addition to this response would be whether we need to download the ISO and mount/burn it, or whether we can install it directly somehow via a link? I haven't been able to find an answer to this.

Comment: @ausairman 1) Download ISO. 2) Mount it (you don't need to burn it, but you can if you like, of course). 3) In Visual Studio 2012, go to Help -> Add and Remove Help Content. 4) In "Installation Source", select Disk, and put: "F:\helpcontentsetup.msha", where F: should be replaced with the drive letter where you mounted the ISO. It should be straightforward from there on.

Comment: The link seems no longer accessible now.

Comment: @user54321 link is still accessible.

Answer (score 4):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/9/2/8928585D-136D-4528-AECC-2F211902A8D7/VS2012Documentation.iso 
The help documentation for vs 2012 ultimate is very much available at the link provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I remember looking for this as well a while ago, and (although I may be incorrect) there is no reasonable way to do this. There is still the documentation available on CD but as far as I'm aware you must be an MSDN subscriber, but as you found out there are no longer the ISOs available for download - shame really as they were useful.

The only way to get it is to beg, steal or borrow (but really not the second option...) the CDs from somebody who has an MSDN subscription and is willing to let you use them. However, just for the record, I imagine this is against the terms of sale.